# Wide long table in landscape mode in longtable environment with long column headers

Tags: longtable, two-column, landscape, column-width

I am trying to make a longtable in **two column article**, that will need to continue to the next page in a **single column** manner. Thus I am using **longtable** environment. since the table is wider too, I need to make it **landscape**. And it have **lengthy column headers**, column width is fitting to colum header textwidth, I tried this (code is  given below). But I need to make it fit to length of page in landscape mode. Now I can see only half of the page. The problem is regarding with **How to make lengthy column headers(content of the column also long) into multiple line with longtable, landscape and twocolumn environment?**

I also found some package **xltabular**. But i didn't find any documentation about this. Link about this also helpful(i got a template from over leaf but didn't worked for me.).

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\title{A longtable + tabularx example, using xltabular}
\section{heokvkxdovk}
\begin{document}
\afterpage{%
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
   % \thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
\centering
\begin{longtable} {|p{0.03cm}|p{0.08cm}|p{0.04cm}|p{0.15cm}|p{0.23cm}|p{0.12cm}|p{0.1cm}|p{0.1cm}|}
\caption{A sample wide and long table.} \label{tab:long} \\

\hline  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Study}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Approach}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Application No.}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Concept Extraction or Concept Mapping model}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Feature generation}} &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Result}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Input}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Dataset}} \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{8}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page} \\
\hline  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Study}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Approach}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Application No.}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Concept Extraction or Concept Mapping model}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Feature generation}} &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Result}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Input}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Dataset}} \\ \hline 
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{8}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline
\endlastfoot

One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\

\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! (i) `longtable` doesn't work in two column documents, (ii) in your MWE (Minimal Working Example) the `afterpage` package is missed, (iii) `\section` title shoud not be before `\begin{document}, your MWE is one column document ...

Comment: \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{lXllXllX} in combination with the \thead commsnd from the makecell package for the column headers should work.

Comment: I forgot to mention that, cells content in the real table are also longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As I mentioned in comment, `longtable` doesn't work in two columns documents. For using it in such documents, you need to change document before `longtable` into one `column` type and after it return to two column. This, regardless that you use `afterpage`, left empty space before and after table.
- it is not clear, if cells content in the real table body are longer as are  presented in your (dummy) table example. If it is not, than instead of `p{...}` columns type is better to use for example `l` columns

**Edit:**

- with use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{....}` in column headers you overwrite your column specifications. You should remove their use and eventually instead them use

```
\bfseries Study & \bfseries Approach & \bfseries Application No. 
                & \bfseries Concept Extraction or Concept Mapping model 
                & \bfseries Feature generation  
                & \bfseries Result  
                & \bfseries Input    
                & \bfseries Dataset     \\ \hline
```

- another solution can be use `thead{...}` commands from the `makcell` comands and manually break column headers into more lines and use in table for example `l` column types. However, if texts in cells are longer and you like to automatically break it into more lines, than this solution will not give desired result

One of possible solution for your table is:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % two column document

\usepackage{longtable, 
            makecell}    % new
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % new
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}   % new
\title{A longtable + tabularx example, using xltabular}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{heokvkxdovk}
\lipsum[1-2]
\afterpage{%
    \onecolumn
    \begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{ | *{8}{l|} }
                 %{|p{0.03cm}|p{0.08cm}|p{0.04cm}|p{0.15cm}|
                 %  p{0.23cm}|p{0.12cm}|p{0.1cm} |p{0.1cm}|}
\caption{A sample wide and long table.} 
\label{tab:long}                                        \\
    \hline  
\thead{Study}   & \thead{Approach}  
                & \thead{Application\\ No.}  
                & \thead{Concept Extraction\\ or Mapping model}  
                & \thead{Feature\\ generation}
                &\thead{Result}  
                & \thead{Input}     & \thead{Dataset}   \\ 
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{ -- continued from previous page}            \\
    \hline  
\thead{Study}   & \thead{Approach}  
                & \thead{Application\\ No.}
                & \thead{Concept Extraction\\ or Mapping model}
                & \thead{Feature\\ generation}
                &\thead{Result}
                & \thead{Input}     & \thead{Dataset}   \\
    \hline
\endhead
     \hline 
\multicolumn{8}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on next page}}            \\ 
\endfoot
    \hline
\endlastfoot
%%%% table body
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778&One & abcdef ghjijklmn \\
\end{longtable}
    \end{landscape}
\twocolumn
}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

- for use of the `xltabular` table, you need to decide, if all columns have equal width. In this case the table specification and document preamble can be for example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % two column document
\usepackage{ragged2e}                   % new
\usepackage{xltabular}                  % new
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}     % new
\newcommand\bfc{\small\bfseries\hfil}   % new
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}                  
\title{An example of use of the \texttt{xltabular} package}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{heokvkxdovk}
\lipsum[1-2]
\afterpage{%
    \onecolumn
    \begin{landscape}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{| c | *{7}{L|} }
\caption{A sample wide and long table.}
\label{tab:long}                                        \\
    \hline
\bfc  Study & \bfc  Approach
            & \bfc  App. No. *
            & \bfc  CE or MM *
            & \bfc  Feature g. *
            & \bfc  Result
            & \bfc  Input
            & \bfc  Dataset                             \\
   \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{ -- continued from previous page}            \\
    \hline
\bfc  Study & \bfc  Approach
            & \bfc  App. No. *
            & \bfc  CE or MM *
            & \bfc  Feature g. *
            & \bfc  Result
            & \bfc  Input
            & \bfc  Dataset                             \\
    \hline
\endhead
     \hline
\multicolumn{5}{p{0.5\linewidth}}{\small 
                                App. No.: Application Number\newline
                                CE or MM: Concept Extraction or Mapping Model\newline  
                                Feature g.: Feature generation}   
            &   
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on next page}}    \\
\endfoot
    \hline
\multicolumn{8}{p{\linewidth}}{\small
                                App. No.: Application Number\newline
                                CE or MM: Concept Extraction or Mapping Model\newline
                                Feature g.: Feature generation}   \\
\endlastfoot
%%%% table body
\end{xltabular}
    \end{landscape}
\twocolumn
}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

which generate (showed is the last part of table):

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that, cells content in the real table body are also longer.This answer resolved my problem with little modification. I had edited question and post the worked answer below, may will help anyone .

Comment: @puppypuppy, better than provide own answer (which actually will not help anyone) is edit your question and to your MWE show one or  two rows of real table, which contain the longest  cells' contents.

Comment: @puppypuppy, see edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    \onecolumn
    \begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.04\linewidth}|p{0.13\linewidth}|p{0.05\linewidth}|p{0.21\linewidth}|p{0.16\linewidth}|p{0.16\linewidth}|p{0.16\linewidth}|} %new


\caption{A sample wide and long table.} 
\label{tab:long}                                        \\
    \hline  
\thead{Study}   & \thead{Approach}  
                & \thead{Applica- \\ tion No.}  
                & \thead{Concept Extraction\\ or Mapping model}  
                &\thead{Result}  
                & \thead{Input}     
                & \thead{Dataset}   \\ 
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{ -- continued from previous page}            \\
    \hline  
\thead{Study}   & \thead{Approach}  
                & \thead{Applica \\tion No.}
                & \thead{Concept Extraction\\ or Mapping model}
                &\thead{Result}
                & \thead{Input}     & \thead{Dataset}   \\
    \hline
\endhead
     \hline 
\multicolumn{7}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on next page}}            \\ 
\endfoot
    \hline
\endlastfoot


%%%% table body
Dummy text &
Dummy text &
Dummy No &
Lengthy Dummy text  my will spilt in multiple rows &
Dummy text&
Dummy text&
Dummy text \\
Dummy text &
Dummy text &
Dummy No &
Lengthy Dummy text  my will spilt in multiple rows &
Dummy text&
Dummy text&
Dummy text\\
Dummy text &
Dummy text &
Dummy No &
Lengthy Dummy text  my will spilt in multiple rows &
Dummy text&
Dummy text&
Dummy text\\

\end{longtable}
    \end{landscape}
\twocolumn
}
```